# Trying to connect to EC2 mysql from my local machine

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to my EC2 instance from my localhost machine and am getting the error "Connection failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."
In the security group I have opened port MYSQL 3306 to all IP address, and in my my.conf file I have change bind-address to 0.0.0.0.
Please let me know what else I can do to try to connect to the server's mysql database.

Comment: Probably a silly question but have you restarted MySQL?

Comment: I have indeed. And set a new user with full privileges using % for host

Comment: Are you running any extra firewalls on the instance itself? Any iptables rules or anything?

Comment: I am not sure, is there a way I can check this?

Comment: Have you verified you can connect to that port from your client - e.g. `telnet 1.2.3.4 3306` (obviously replace 1.2.3.4 with your ec2 host/ip address)? If you cannot make this connection from your client to your server that means something is blocking it on either client or server side.

Comment: I just tried telnet 1.2.3.4 and got "Could not open connection to the host..." any idea what steps I can take next?

Comment: Replace `1.2.3.4` with the IP address of your remote server.

Comment: Server is set to Multi_User & Not Single_User right ?

Answer (score 0):

In security group add inbound access rule for SSH

I think the problem should be this. Because, accessing with out ssh rule is not possible.
And try to ping instance ip from your local cmd.